# Why would I create an interface for each mapper class?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

In cases of MVC applications where the model is split into separate domain and mapper layers, why would you give each of the mapper classes its own interface?

I have seen a few examples now, some from well respected developers such as the case with this blog, http://site.svn.dasprids.de/trunk/application/modules/blog/models/

I suspect that its because the developers are expecting the code to be re-used by others who may have their own back-ends.  Is this the case?  Or am I missing something?

Note that in the examples I have seen, developers are not necessarily creating interfaces for the domain objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since interfaces are contracts between classes (I'm kinda assuming that you already know that). When a class expects you to pass an object with as specific interface, the goal is to inform you, that this class instance expect specific method to be executable on said object.

The only case that i can think of, when having a defined interface for data mappers make sense **might be** when using [unit of work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) to manage the persistence. But even then it would make more sense to simply inject a factory, that can create data mappers.

**TL;DR:** someone's been overdoing.

> <sub>**P.S.:** it is quite possible, that I am completely wrong about this one, since I'm a bit biased on the subject - my mappers contain only 3 (+constructor) public methods: `fetch()`, `store()` and `remove()` .. though names method names tend to change. I prefer to take the retrieval conditions from domain object, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11943107/727208).</sub>