# Handling items in the collection pattern by a data mapper

Tags: php, design-patterns, collections, architecture, datamapper

My question is related to the update section of [@tereško's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/727208/teresko's) answer in "[Who should handle the conditions in complex queries, the data mapper or the service layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942842/who-should-handle-the-conditions-in-complex-queries-the-data-mapper-or-the-serv/11943107#11943107)" Below is the code for reference and convenience.

```
$category = new Category;
$category->setTitle( 'privacy' );

$list = new ArticleCollection;

$list->setCondition( $category );
$list->setDateRange( mktime( 0, 0, 0, 12, 9, 2001) );
// it would make sense, if unset second value for range of dates 
// would default to NOW() in mapper

$mapper = new ArticleCollectionMapper;
$mapper->fetch( $list );

foreach ( $list as $article )
{
    $article->setFlag( Article::STATUS_REMOVED );
}

$mapper->store( $list );
```

In this code `ArticleCollection` is a collection of Domain Objects, let's call them `Article`s. The moment the `ArticleCollectionMapper` fetches data from the database, assigning it to `$list`, instances of `Article` need to be made (for each row). Would the instances of `Article` be added to our collection instance (`$list`) via a method like `$list->addArticle($newArticle)`, should a Factory Object like `ArticleFactory` be used for that, or is there another option I haven't considered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't think to actually use a factory object to add the articles. You may see yourself using one to make the instance of `Article` (in the second example), though. What I went ahead and did was add an `addArticles ()` method to the `ArticleCollection` instance. This way you can simply call the method on your instance of `ArticleCollection` from the mapper. `ArticleCollectionMapper` may look something like:

```
class ArticleCollectionMapper extends DataMapperAbstract
{
    public function fetch ( ArticleCollection $articles )
    {
        $prepare = $this->connection->prepare( "SELECT ..." );
        $prepare->execute();
        // filter conditions

        $articles->addArticles( $prepare->fetchAll() );
    }
}
```

You'd need to do some filtering by getting the conditions from the `ArticleCollection` instance, which is excluded from the snippet above. Then our domain object's `addArticles()` implementation would look similar following:

```
class ArticleCollection extends DomainObjectAbstract
{
    protected $collection = array();

    public function addArticles ( Array $articles )
    {
        foreach ( $articles as $article )
        {
            $articleCollectionItem = new Article;
            $articleCollectionItem->setParams( $article );
            // however you prefer filling your list with `Article` instances

            $this->collection[] = $articleCollectionItem;
        }
    }
}
```

You may also want to add an `addArticle()` method depending on your needs, and then just replacing what's within the `foreach` above with a call to `addArticle()`. Note that the above examples are extremely simplified and code *will* need to be adapted in order to meet your standards.

Comment: hey jeremy, thank you for your answer. In fact in the mean time i used a similar solution. Rather then using the addArticle you showed i have a newArticle and an addArticle method in the ArticleCollection. The first one just returns an article object, which the datamapper populate by its own method. And the addArticle Method just adds a given article object to the list. So you are right one does not need a factory for that.